# How to use an exported class inside an Angular2 component

Tags: angular

So I've got this class in a separate file:

```
export class MyModel {
      votes: number;
      title: string;
      link: string;

      constructor() {
        this.title = 'Github';
        ///
      }

      myfunc()

     ///
}
```

And I want to use its props in this component, but can't figure out how to do it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from './models.model';

@Component({
  selector: ///
  templateUrl: ///
  styleUrls: ///
})
export class SomeComponent {
    //declare somehow..?
}
```

Comment: you can declare it as `let myObj = new MyModel()` inside your `SomeComponent`;

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from './models.model';

@Component({
  selector: ///
  templateUrl: ///
  styleUrls: ///
})
export class SomeComponent {

  public objOne: MyModel;
  public objTwo: MyModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.objOne = {
      title : 'First Object'
    };

    // or you can declare it as below
    this.objTwo = new MyModel();
  }

}
```

You can check `app.component.ts` code on page [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare an object using the `new` keyword and then use that object to access `title` and other attribute.

Example:

```
var obj = new MyModel();
console.log(obj.title);
```